# Store data in ( .wav) format from RTL-SDR device using c#

Tags: c#, .net, rtl-sdr, iq

I am able to connect with RTL-SDR using librtlsdr.dll  and libusb-1.0.dll  by using (https://github.com/nandortoth/rtlsdr-manager) wrapper in c# .netcore3.0 .

Started getting sampledata from device by set device frequency. i am getting data in List of IQ .

I need to store this data in .wav file .its very easy with chrome.usb.bulktransfer function. this function provide int8array,int32array,uint8array that is directly write able to .wav file .

i don't have an idea how it could be done using c# from IQ array

any suggestions or code samples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

To save IQ data to .wav file, you can write I component to one channel and Q component to the other channel ([reference](https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr/issues/73#issuecomment-340438842)).

> The "in-phase" (real) is typically placed in the left channel and the "quadrature" (imag) part in the right channel.

You can use [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) to achieve that. First, you need `BinaryWriter` to convert `int` array (IQ data) to `Stream` (`byte` array). Then, you can use `MultiplexingWaveProvider` to create .wav file with 2 channels.

```
var iqDataList = device.GetSamplesFromAsyncBuffer(maxCount);

var iStream = new MemoryStream();
var qStream = new MemoryStream();

var iWriter = new BinaryWriter(iStream);
var qWriter = new BinaryWriter(qStream);

foreach (var iqData in iqDataList)
{
    iWriter.Write(iqData.I);
    qWriter.Write(iqData.Q);
}

var iComponent = new RawSourceWaveStream(iStream, new WaveFormat(rate, bits, 1));
var qComponent = new RawSourceWaveStream(qStream, new WaveFormat(rate, bits, 1));

var waveProvider = new MultiplexingWaveProvider(new IWaveProvider[] {iComponent, qComponent}, 2);

WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(filename, waveProvider);

iComponent.Dispose();
qComponent.Dispose();

iWriter.Dispose();
qWriter.Dispose();
```